# How to make a php page and use a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I want to create a special php and javascript page, but I want it to use my Wordpress theme that is already installed. How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. What do you mean with "special php and javascript wordpress page"?

Comment: sorry ... a PHP PAGE .. i want to use my own PHP and JAVASCRIPT. but i want to use it in my wordpress so i want it to look like my wordpress THEME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by including the header and footer from wordpress, and putting your own code in the middle. Such as this:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-blog-header.php";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/[YOUR THEME]/header.php";
// your code goes here
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/[YOUR THEME]/footer.php";
```

I haven't tested this on newer versions of wordpress, but in the past that has worked. You can even include the wpconfig file if you want to use some of those variables, such as the database connection information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome solution. This was the only solution that worked for me. Using third party solution or creating child theme/templates didnt provide pure php. Props to Jeremy. Tested with Wordpress 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

See [Integrating WordPress with Your Website « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) on how to pull the header and other includes into a static php page/file, like:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
get_header(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE);
    require('./wp-blog-header.php');

    get_header();

    query_posts('showposts=1');

    get_footer();

?>
```